# How to the 3 joined table insert data with stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables: `Products`, `Categories` and `productFeature`.

- `Products` have one to one relation with `productFeature`
- `Products` have one to many relation with `Categories`

I'm using a stored procedure to insert data into the tables. My problem is: I can't do this.

I'm using .NET Core, Entity Framework, SQL Server.

The stored procedure I wrote looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_products_with_productFeature_insert222
    @name nvarchar(max),
    @url nvarchar(max),
    @stock int,
    @price decimal(9,2),
    @discountPrice decimal(9,2),
    @barcode int,
    @categoryId int,
    @width int,
    @height int,
    @color nvarchar(max),
    @newId int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        p.Name, p.URL, p.Stock, p.Price,
        p.DiscountPrice, p.Barcode, p.CategoryId,
        pf.Width, pf.Height, pf.Color 
    FROM 
        Products p
    JOIN
        Categories c ON p.CategoryId = c.Id
    JOIN
        productFeatures pf ON p.Id = pf.Id

    INSERT INTO Products (p.Name, p.URL, p.Stock, p.Price, p.DiscountPrice, p.Barcode, p.CategoryId) 
    VALUES (@name, @url, @stock, @price, @discountPrice, @barcode, @categoryId)

    INSERT INTO productFeatures (Width, Height, Color) 
    VALUES (@width, @height, @color)

    SET @newId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    RETURN @newId
END


EXEC  sp_products_with_productFeature_insert222 'name','a',2,2,1,21,1,23,12,'red'
```

This is the error I get when I run it:

[image]

For those who want the error message:

> Procedure or function 'sp_products_with_productFeature_insert222' expects parameter '@newId', which was not supplied.

Comment: Do you have more details on why you cant do this?  An error?  Design issue?  Other?

Comment: yes, when I click the run button, I get an error message. I'll edit the topic now.

Comment: A variable to hold value of newid is missing. try below

exec sp_products_with_productFeature_insert222 'name','a',2,2,1,21,1,23,12,'red',@out_value

Comment: When I enter a number manually, it accepts the query. No data is added to the product productFeature table. Writing @newId gives an error: Must declare the scalar variable "@newId".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stored Procedure in MsSql expecting output parameter as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59305171/stored-procedure-in-mssql-expecting-output-parameter-as-input)

Comment: No. Now it only works if I manually type the Id of the last record that added the @newId field.

Comment: I can't automatically populate the properties of my productFeatures table with the value from @newId.

Comment: Typing @newId into the secondary key of my productFeatures table gives an error: Must declare the scalar variable "@newId".

Comment: I can't follow what you're saying. `@newId` is an *output* parameter. It is not a field in your table. A "record" does not "add" an output parameter. You also do not need to `return @newId`, because it is an `output` parameter. The question I linked to shows you how to get the value from an output parameter. You must declare a variable, associate that variable with the output parameter when calling the procedure, and then read the variable once the procedure has executed.

Answer (score 0):

A comment cannot do this justice. And there really is no excuse for not posting your code as text in your question rather than an image.

Taking the query your execute that produces the error and listing the values you provide as parameters, we have:

```
exec sp_products_with_productFeature_insert222 
@name            'a',
@url             'a',
@stock            2,
@price            2,
@discountPrice    1,
@barcode          21,
@categoryId       1,
@width            23,
@height           12,
@color            'red'
@newId            <this is missing>
```

This is not a valid query - I just formatted it to help highly which values you pass correspond to which parameter of the procedure. The last parameter is an output parameter and the language requires that YOU provide a "location" that can effectively be written to by the procedure for storing the value it sets internally. You provide this so your code can access that value and (presumably) do something with it.

In addition, the last line of your procedure is `RETURN @newId`. By convention we do not use the return value of a stored procedure to provide "data". The convention is to use it to simply indicate success or failure. And it makes no sense to use a return value here anyways since you specifically implemented an output parameter for this purpose. So just remove that RETURN statement.

To execute your procedue, use the following as an example. I omitted most of the parameter values in the EXEC statement - I expect you to understand that.

```
declare @id int;
exec dbo.sp_products_with_productFeature_insert222 'a','a', ...  ,@id OUTPUT;
select @id;
```

The difference here is that a variable is declared to "receive" the value stored in the OUTPUT parameter. You pass that variable as the output parameter. After execution, you can then examine the value returned by the procedure.  Here I just select it.